# How to enable pjsip bluetooth in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, pjsip, avaudiosession

we made VoIP app using pjsip and we required to add support of the Bluetooth. For that, we added the following code:-

```
pjmedia_aud_dev_route route = PJMEDIA_AUD_DEV_ROUTE_BLUETOOTH;
pj_status_t status =
pjsua_snd_set_setting(PJMEDIA_AUD_DEV_CAP_INPUT_ROUTE, &route,
                      PJ_TRUE);
NSLog(@"statuys is--->%d",status);
```

But above code give status code "420008".so how to add Bluetooth in pjsip.

so anyone has a solution for that then please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need use AVAudioSession to route the sound in bluetooth device but before routing you need to call pjsip library for sound `pjsua_set_snd_dev(0,0);`

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth error:&error];
```

**Happy to help you :)**

Comment: I tried your given solution but again give the same error "420008".if you have code snippets to enabling Bluetooth successful then please help me.